# JavaScript tree / treegrid libraries

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a good JavaScript tree / treegrid package.  Now -- before you answer:

It needs to be able to perform well with *lots* of nodes.  Perhaps 1,000 sibling nodes.  It needs to be able to draw to a usable state within 2 or 3 seconds with 1,000 nodes.  It doesn't necessarily need to draw all 1,000 nodes at once -- if it supports some sort of "smart rendering" or fake scrolling.

Beyond that, column resizing, drag and drop, inline editing would all be nice, although I could probably add that functionality myself.

I've already tried dojo's tree and yahoo's YUI treeview.  Both are too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here for others:

Here's one that I've found, which isn't free (except for GPL), but seems reasonably priced:

http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTreeGrid/index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure you need a tree for your purposes. What I would recommend is you take a look at [Steve Dekorte's vertex.js](http://github.com/stevedekorte/vertex.js) for your purposes. I can tell you that it scales extremely well.

Comment: I'm not really sure how that would help me.  I actually do need the UI elements here - I need for it to draw a tree & a treegrid, as all javascript trees do.  I just need for it to perform well with a large number of nodes too.